# How do I configure Godot 4.1.1 to use Rider as the IDE for C#?

Tags: c#, godot

I can't find out how to do this. I've installed the godot plugin into Rider.

I found two tutorials, one says to open Godot, and go into Project Settings and find Mono and change some settings. However for me, the Mono option does not exist and I can't see any other options that would work.

The second tutorial I found said to point Rider at the Godot folder, and it would detect that it was a Godot project. I did this and it didn't detect that it was a Godot project and I don't have any intellisense.

I am using the Mono version of Godot.

Can someone advise how to get Rider to work? For unity, I simply pointed it in the settings to Rider and it worked perfectly without any faff, but Godot is proving difficult.

I don't have enough rep to create a Rider tag.

Answer (score 4):

Took me a while to get this working.

Ensure you're using Mono godot.

Go to Project > Tools > C# > Create C# Solution

Then open the solution within Rider, and ensure you have the Godot plugin installed.

It should automatically load the Godot interface, but if it doesn't (which it didn't for me) you can right click the `.sln` file within Rider and open it (even if the project is already open). It should then detect it and work.